# Append item to list, which is dict value

Tags: python, dictionary, append

I'm trying to create the dict which is "key": [value...]. When I use update function for dict and append for list of values, I get None:

[image: My code results]

The code block is:

```
some_items = ["val1", "val2", "val3"]


my_dict = {}
some_it = 0
test_list = []
for item in some_items:
    my_dict.update(
        {
            some_it : [].append(item)
        }
    )
    test_list.append(item)
    some_it +=1
```

Finally I'd like to get sorting function, that filters data types for some criteria (key) and append all found values as value list to my dict.

Comment: Appending to a list in a dict is like any other operation. Do you know how to add a number to an existing value in the dictionary, for example?

Comment: @AMC yes. I know that. But in my case I needed to use `setdefault` as @Błotosmętek mentioned

Comment: Well using `setdefault` isn’t absolutely necessary. You should check out [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) by the way, it should get you the same result and I find it a cleaner to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[].append(item)` appends an item to the empty list, then throws away the result. What you probably wanted to do is:

```
for some_it, item in enumerate(some_items):
    my_dict.setdefault(some_it, []).append(item)
```

Comment: Yep. Its what I need!